# apache camel routing based on active or inactive consumer

Tags: jms, apache-camel

I'm not sure about which is the best pattern to implement this situation:

I have a component that routes message from a queue A to my application queue B.

Now I want that the routing component was able to detect whether my application is active or not and in this second case, deliver the message from A to another queue C.

I think that there are several implementation to reach this goal, maybe using topic subscription or dynamic routing..

Does anybody solved this problem and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the [camel-loadbalancer](http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html) failover support...

```
from("direct:start")
// here we will load balance if IOException was thrown
// any other kind of exception will result in the Exchange as failed
// to failover over any kind of exception we can just omit the exception
// in the failOver DSL
.loadBalance().failover(IOException.class)
    .to("direct:x", "direct:y", "direct:z");
```